# How is enable_if used for removing code

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I am using enable_if statements for removing possible methods under consideration.

```
#include "gmpxx.h"
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct is_ring_field {
};

template <>
struct is_ring_field<int> {
  static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct is_ring_field<mpq_class> {
  static const bool value = true;
};

template<typename T>
std::enable_if<is_ring_field<T>::value,int> RankMat(T const& Input)
{
  return 10;
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if<(not is_ring_field<T>::value),int> RankMat(T const& Input)
{
  return 20;
}

int main()
{
  int M1=10;
  mpq_class M2=3;
  std::cerr << "FICT rank(M1)=" << RankMat(M1) << "\n";
  std::cerr << "FICT rank(M2)=" << RankMat(M2) << "\n";
}
```

The final objective is to have methods that varies depending on the algebraic data type on input. For other traits it worked for me, but not this one. In this case the compiler strangely says that the call is ambiguous, in other words that **std::enable_if** has failed.

Comment: Look at the two overloads for `RankMat`.  What part of the overloads differ?  Can that part be the only part of the function that differs to be a valid overload?

Comment: Haven't you forget `typename std::enable_if<*,*>::type`?

Comment: Yes, I found out after writing my message, sorry about that. Both messages from clang++ and g++ were unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

`std::enable_if<>` is a valid type; you need to use its `type` member for the SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_ring_field<T>::value,int>::type RankMat(T const& Input)
{
  return 10;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<(not is_ring_field<T>::value),int>::type RankMat(T const& Input)
{
  return 20;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You've just placed it to the wrong position.
Try this:

```
template<typename T>
int RankMat(T const& Input, typename std::enable_if<is_ring_field<T>::value,T>::type* = 0)
{
      return 10;
}

template<typename T>
int RankMat(T const& Input, typename std::enable_if<(not is_ring_field<T>::value),T>::type* = 0)
{
      return 20;
}
```

or this:

```
template<typename T, typename TT = is_ring_field<T>>
int RankMat(T const& Input)
{
      return TT::value ? 10 : 20;
}
```

Comment: actually this is not the only context allowed to generate soft error in sfinae... see [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7MK1lLnULUVp04JY) and [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SlFEgbxo6ZzxDATO). The one you proposed is actually available since c++11 before function template parameters weren't allowed to be defaulted...

Comment: Right. Quick answer is a bad idea. I gave wrong information. This is a lesson for me.